# Copy multiple columns and paste into another workbook (destination)

Tags: excel, vba

I have been declaring the data I copy as a range and using .copy destination to paste.
However, when used with multiple columns it produces the error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2V9r.png)

I have four different sets of data I would like to copy.  Here is what I have:

```
Sub newMacro()

'   Copy and paste all data

Dim copyNames As Range, pasteNames As Range, copyAmounts As Range, pasteAmounts, copyDates As Range, pasteDates As Range, _
copyPayment As Range, pastePayment As Range

Set copyNames = Workbooks("2019 11 November.xls").Worksheets(2).Columns("F")
Set copyAmounts = Workbooks("2019 11 November.xls").Worksheets(2).Columns("AR")
Set copyDates = Workbooks("2019 11 November.xls").Worksheets(2).Columns("AI")
Set copyPayment = Workbooks("2019 11 November.xls").Worksheets(2).Columns("AJ")

Set pasteNames = Workbooks("VBA Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")
Set pasteAmounts = Workbooks("VBA Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")
Set pasteDates = Workbooks("VBA Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("D")
Set pastePayment = Workbooks("VBA Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets.Columns("E")

copyNames.Copy Destination:=pasteNames
copyAmoutns.Copy Destination:=pasteAmounts
copyDates.Copy Destination:=pasteDates
copyPayment.Copy Destination:=pastePayment

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance all

Comment: Side note: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. You've got some typos.

Comment: If you compare the line `Set pastePayment = Workbooks("VBA Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets.Columns("E")`, specifically, `.Worksheets.Columns("E")`, to the other lines, I think you'll spot your error.

Comment: Thanks, was unaware of those typos.  I fixed them, added option explicit and am still receiving an error message stating the object variable is not set - anything else I might be missing?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with your revised code and note what line throws the error?

Comment: Posted the new edits.  Let me know what you find

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: `pasteAmounts` is implicitly declared as a Variant instead of being explicitly declared as a Range.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious  Thanks guys, the code runs without error.  Is there a way I can paste subsequent data directly below previously pasted data? (Ie. data set 1 pastes from rows 1 to n, I need the next set of data to paste to the next row beneath the nth row)

Comment: Yes, you want to look into `Range.Offset`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset

Answer (score 0):

> `pasteAmoutns` is not declared

[image: BigBen]

*As **@BigBen** suggested, use **`Option Explicit`** to avoid spelling errors.*

Comment: You missed the big error: `.Worksheets.Columns("E")` as I pointed out in my second comment.

Comment: And you missed `copyAmoutns` too.

Comment: @BigBen ***You*** say I missed something, but ***I*** say it was simply a collaborative answer!  =)